# Select first TD child from a TR parent with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have the following:

```
<tr>
  <td>Value 1</td>
  <td>Value 2</td>
  <td>Value 3</td>
</tr>
```

Now, with jQuery I do this:

```
var jTR = $('tr');
var jFirstChild = jTR.find(':first-child');
```

but jFirstChild.length returns 0.

I also find that when I do jTR.length it too returns 0.

Ultimately, I am trying to find the first child of the table row and then remove that first child.

When I do this:

```
<div>
  <p>Value 1</p>
  <p>Value 2</p>
  <p>Value 3</p>
 </div>
```

with

```
var jDiv = $('div');
```

jDiv.length returns 3 as expected.

Can I not select a TR element directly?

Comment: make sure your code is in dom ready handler like `jQuery(function(){var jTR = $('tr');
var jFirstChild = jTR.find(':first-child');})`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: It is.. all preloaded I've also tried this out in JSFiddle too

Comment: There's nothing special about the `tr`. If there's something wrong,  you've not provided it in the question. http://jsfiddle.net/qpy9U/

Comment: Yours works. I don't have the <table> tags http://jsfiddle.net/d72zR/3/ So why doesn't it work without the <table> tags?

Comment: Also found it worked better to my liking if I changed it `jTR.find(':first');`

Comment: You don't have `table` tags??? Why not? That's not valid HTML. The browser (Firefox anyway) is just removing the `<tr>` and `<td>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('tr').length` is no longer `0` if it's wrapped inside of a `table`, at least in Chrome. Perhaps the DOM parser for Chrome doesn't create the `tr` when it's outside of a `table` because it's invalid HTML. See [my working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5dau/).

Comment: Seems Firefox behaves the same way. Just thought for debugging purpose I might get away with out using <table> guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('tr td:first')
```

But you have to make sure $('tr').length > 0

When people got $('tr').length === 0, the TR element may be not attached into the document, or in the wrong context.